# How to distribute (arrange) blocks programatically in a Simulink library?

Tags: simulink, s-function

I'm using Simulink's Legacy Code Tool to generate an S-Function block driver library from legacy C device drivers for an embedded target.

Driver blocks are generated iteratively and end up in the library **target_LCT_sfun_drivers** by way of LCT's `slblock_generate` sub-command using a MATLAB script, eg:

```
legacy_code('slblock_generate', lctSpecs, 'target_LCT_sfun_drivers')
```

When the script finishes, **target_LCT_sfun_drivers** holds all my driver blocks, but they are all stacked upon one another.

What can I add to the script that distributes the blocks programmatically, to avoid manually dragging them off of the 'stack'?